# Why bind variables amount isn't valid?

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, spring-data-cassandra

I am overriding CQL statement like this:

```
    @Query("INSERT INTO message (content,email,magic_number,title) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);")
    Message save(Message message);
```

but Spring throws Invalid amount of bind variables.

What is wrong here?

---

EDIT:

I am adding message class:

```
@Table(value = "message")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Message {

    @Column("email")
    private String email;

    @Column("title")
    private String title;

    @Column("content")
    private String content;

    @PrimaryKey
    @Column("magic_number")
    private int magicNumber;
}
```

and also json whitch is send to the api:

```
{
    "email": "name@example.com",
    "title": "title",
    "content": "text123",
    "magic_number": 101
}
```

Comment: Also add `Message` class code

Answer (score 0):

Spring is expecting 4 bind variables which aligns with the 4 bind markers (?) you have specified in the query.

To make it work you'd have to have add the 4 input parameters to the save() method.

If you extend CassandraRepository the save method is already implemented for you.  Is there a reason you're trying to override it?